# Windows form c# component is not added to form if is not added in the in the same class that it has been instantiated

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

So, Basically i have a Filter class which generates a panel with the components i need for the filter (plus other things)

```
   public Panel panel;
    public Filter(string labelText)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = labelText;

        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        panel.Visible = true;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Black;

    }

    public Panel GetFilter()
    {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Then on the form code, call GetFilter() to add the panel

```
 Filter f = new Filter("name")
 Controls.Add(f.GetFilter());
```

The filter does not show, hmm lets see if the code in filter is well writen.

```
        //copy of the Fiter constructor
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "label text";

        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        panel.Visible = true;
        panel.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;


        Controls.Add(panel);
```

well that did work, one last thing, lets see if i can the panel from the filter class

```
  public Panel panel;
    public Filter(string labelText, Form f)
    {

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = labelText;

        panel.Controls.Add(label);
        panel.Visible = true;
        panel.BackColor = Color.Black;
        f.Controls.Add(f);
    }

    public Panel GetFilter()
    {
        return panel;
    }
```

heck, that also worked, what i am missing here? Non of the above working examples works for me because filter will be call from an abstract class to be added to a parent Panel. What do i have to do for the panel to be shown?

pd:The background colors are for testing if the panel is added.

Comment: You are redeclaring `Panel panel = new Panel();` in your constructor which makes it local. Simply Assign a value to `panel` instead of redeclaring it `panel = new Panel();`

Comment: What is Filter here? Is it a user Control?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I think it is a class.

Comment: `internal Panel panel = null; (...) public Filter(string labelText) { panel = new Panel(); (...) }`

Comment: Also, note that you're not setting `panel.Size` or `panel.Location` anywhere, nor the `Dock` or `Anchor` properties, so this all depends on the container (which, apparently, is a Form). As of now, your new Panel will have default Size `(200, 100)` and Location `(0, 0)`.